# Is there any difference between "not much use" and "no use"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Are these sentences equally acceptable?

```
It is not much use trying to convince him of that.
It is no use trying to convince him of that.
There's not much use trying to convince him of that.
There's no use trying to convince him of that.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are similar, but `no use` is stronger than `not much use`. By stronger, I mean that the probability of success in `no use` is lower than in `not much use`. With `not much use`, the softener `much` indicates that there may be some possibility of a successful outcome, even it if is still very unlikely.

Of your sentences, 1 and 3 are the same, while 2 and 4 are the same. 2 and 4 are stronger than 1 and 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, kandyman!:)